# Can I use the Boolean feature on strapi to show or hide a component in a collection type

Tags: reactjs, strapi

Would love a little advice on this.
So I have a collection type. In that collection type I have a download button component. Not all of the pages in the collection type require the download button so I would like a way to either show it or hide it. It feels like the boolean feature might work with this but I can't figure it out or find any examples. Any tips out there? The front end is React.js

Comment: Sadly, there's no *out-of-the-box* conditional components switching in Strapi